# What should when a parent has a static class and a child does not?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

I have code that looks like this:

```
Class Parent:
    def someMethod(self):
        return 42

Class Child(Parent):
    def someMethod(self):
        print self.answer
```

The parent has a method that could be static, and (to get rid of Pylint warnings) I want to add a @staticmethod decorator, but then I would want to remove self as an argument.  That would mean the Parent and Child have different input arguments.  Is there any good way to do this besides leaving the code as is?

Comment: Is `Child` meant to inherit from `Parent`?

Comment: *"Is there any good way to do this besides leaving the code as is?"* - The code as it is now doesn't reflect what you are describing. For one (see @Caspar comment) you miss the inheritance information, then you did not define a static method in either of the two, then... Maybe you pasted the wrong code snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to pass a Child when a Parent is expected, then the overriding method should accept the same argument list as the parent's method. It just happens that this specific Parent implementation that method *could* be made static.

Use a `# pylint: disable=X0123` (replace with the appropriate warning code) in the parent to disable the lint warning.